# Removing jQuery Validation on the fly

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm trying to prevent the jQuery Validation plugin from validating if a certain form option (phone only) is selected using $("#form_id").rules("remove", "required"); feature, but it's not working...

All I get is a javascript error when I select phone only: "TypeError: Result of expression 'F' [undefined] is not an object, and the form won't submit since it's still validating required fields.

```
//field validation
$('#location').change(function(){
    location_val = $('#location').val();

    if (location_val == "select") {
        $('.hide').hide();
    }
    else if (location_val == "my_location") {
        $('.hide').hide();
        $('#f_address, #f_address2, #f_city, #f_state_zip, #f_phone').customFadeIn('fast');
        $("#step2").rules("add", "required");
    }
    else if (location_val == "customers_location") {
        $('.hide').hide();
        $('#f_area, #f_phone, #f_city, #f_state_zip').customFadeIn('fast');
        $("#step2").rules("add", "required");
    }
    else if (location_val == "both") {
        $('.hide').hide();
        $('#f_area, #f_address, #f_address2, #f_city, #f_state_zip, #f_phone').customFadeIn('fast');
        $("#step2").rules("add", "required");
    }
    else if (location_val == "phone") {
        $('.hide').hide();
        $('#f_phone').customFadeIn('fast'); 
        $("#step2").rules("remove", "required");

    }
});

$("#step2").validate({
    rules: {
        city: {required: true},
        state: {required: true},
        zip: {required: true}
    }
});
```

Insights appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I accomplished this task is to use a CSS class that is different from the Validation ruleset.  So for fields that are normally 'required' I am generating the elements with a 'requirement' CSS class.  Then I add this in the page:

```
function addRequired() {
    $('.requirement').each(function() {
        $(this).rules("add", {required: true});
    });
}

function removeRequired() {
    $('.requirement').valid(); // can't remember why I have this, but it's in source control now for awhile...
    $('.requirement').each(function() {
        $(this).rules("remove");
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').validate({...});
    addRequired();
});
```

then hook some behavior on your triggering form element (which looks to be a radio button in your case) that when it's selected, call `addRequired()`.  And when it's no longer selected then call `removeRequired()`.  And obviously account for the different validation options on the back end.

Comment: I guess $(this).rules("remove") will remove all rules, not only required ones?